# NoMethodError: undefined method on create of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hello while programming I came across this error below .

```
#NoMethodError: undefined method `inventories' for #<Person:0x35e1538>
```

He gives this error when I send the post to insert

code below

```
def create

    @person = Person.create(person_params)

   if @person.save
      render json: @person, status: :created, location: @persons
    else
      render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age, :gender, :lonlat, :infected)
    end
```

Angular

```
$scope.SendData = function (people) {
            var data = {
                "person" : {
                    "name": people.name,
                    "age": people.age,  
                    "gender": people.gender,
                    "lonlat": people.lonlat,
                    "infected": people.infected
                }                                
            };
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/people',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data: data
            }).then(function(response) {
                location.reload();
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err)
            });
        };
```

Comment: Please post the complete error in which line it is coming and what is the code there?

Comment: error
 
 "Internal Server Error"
exception
 
 "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `inventories' for #<Person:0x35e1538>>"
status
 
 500

Comment: Can you screen shot the whole error in your browser or in your terminal ?
Not enough informations !!